# Why does printing an array cause lualatex to freeze?

Tags: luatex, debugging

The following MWE sends lualatex into an infinite loop on my machine:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
start = {42};
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring(start))}
\end{document}
```

It seems that I need a variable called `start` and I need to print an array; then I get this:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
 L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
```

Nothing happens after that, and I cannot exit the process with Ctrl+C; I need to use Ctrl+\ to kill it.
GDB says that lua is stuck here:

```
…
#4  0x00007f0ce05c2f9f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtexlua53.so.5
#5  0x00007f0ce05b956e in lua_pcallk ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtexlua53.so.5
#6  0x0000555a19f5f21b in lua_node_filter ()
#7  0x0000555a19f78970 in line_break ()
#8  0x0000555a19eb23c9 in end_graf ()
#9  0x0000555a19eb2429 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000555a19eb07f1 in main_control ()
#11 0x0000555a19eacdfa in main_body ()
#12 0x0000555a19e562c2 in main ()
```

I have LuaTeX Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)

Here's another broken example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
start = "";
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring({42}))}
\end{document}
```

But this works:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
star = "";
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\directlua{tex.sprint(tostring({42}))}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It hangs only with TL2019. I tried all versions from TL2014 to 2021. The output changes for every version.

Comment: Changes between version are not surprising (the output should even change from run to run, since it includes an address); I imagine it's not worth reporting the bug if it doesn't happen in the latest TL?  If so, I think you could post that as an answer and I'll accept it and update — thanks a lot for testing!